# Animating externally loaded SVG with Keith Wood's jQuery SVG plugin

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate the fill color of a group of path's loaded from an external SVG using Keith Wood's [plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html).

First I import the SVG into a div container:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#header-main').svg({loadURL: 'header.svg'});
var svg = $('#header-main').svg('get');
```

});

The SVG file looks like this:

```
<svg>
  <g id="group1">
    <path d="M0,22.943V0.223h1.413v22.721H0z"/>
    <path etc../>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I can change the fill color of the group or individual paths like so:

```
svg.style('#group1 {fill: black}');
```

Now when I try to animate the paths like this:

```
$('path').animate({svgFill: 'blue'}, 500);
```

or
    $('#group1').animate({svgFill: 'blue'}, 500);

or with any other selector, for instance the id of a path, nothing happens.
But if I were to create a path, and animate it like this:

```
    var path1 = svg.createPath(); 
svg.path(path1.move(50, 90).curveC(0, 90, 0, 30, 50, 30). 
    line(150, 30).curveC(200, 30, 200, 90, 150, 90).close(),  
    {fill: 'none', stroke: '#D90000', strokeWidth: 10});
$('path').animate({svgFill: 'blue'}, 500);
```

the path I created animates, but the other paths that were imported from header.svg file do nothing.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is the plugin just not capable of animating external svg?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish approx. the same thing... TWO different ways...  at the top of the code below.. you'll see simple CSS hover tags (that works, at least for simple things)....  and I was ALSO able to get the strokes and fills pulsating through colors, etc, the whole 9 yards...  but not in firefox 3.6, ugh.

Frankly, I can't even get jQuery SVG 1.4.3 to put a freaking SVG into the DOM correctly..  I dunno what the heck is wrong with it..  I swear I've done everything right....  SO I dunno if the below helps..  but one thing to keep in mind..  you may not be able to use this as is...  it seems like you either have to include the xmlns:xlink namespace link and use the xlink transformations...  OR you can blow that stuff away and just do it via CSS...

The hodge-podge of browser compatibility re: SVG is a cluster-f**k, and is making development w/ vector elements so hard, even though it COULD be so cool!!  Too bad everyone doesn't have Safari or Chrome, right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG Tiny 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-tiny.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  baseProfile="tiny" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>     
    g #front {fill:white; fill-opacity:.9; stroke-dasharray:none; stroke-dashoffset:0}
    g:hover #front {fill: red; fill-opacity:.5; stroke-dasharray:30,20;}
    g #back {fill:white;fill-opacity:.8; stroke-dashoffset:0;}
    g:hover #back {stroke-dasharray:30,20; stroke-dashoffset:20; fill: grey; }
</style>
<g id="folderIcon" transform="translate(-15.1,-40.1)">
<g id="sides" transform="translate(-173,-364)">
<path d="m 198,406 0,9 -8,0 0,92 122,0 0,-92 -86,0 0,-9 -28,0 z" id="back" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:3.75;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;" />
 <rect height="84.7" id="front" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:3.608; stroke-linecap:round; stroke-linejoin:round; stroke-miterlimit:4; stroke-opacity:1;" transform="matrix(1,0,-0.397,0.918,0,0)" width="122" x="410" y="468" />
</g>
</g>
<animate xlink:href="#front"
    attributeName="fill" 
    attributeType="CSS"
    from="#ff0" to="#00f" dur="10s" fill="freeze" />
<animate xlink:href="#back"
    attributeName="stroke" 
    attributeType="CSS"
    from="#88ff88"
        to="#880088"
    dur="10s"
    fill="freeze" />
</svg>
```

PS:  If you have any tips besides what you had posted in your original question (which I've tried) to get the inline OR "linked" SVG's working with that French guy's jQ plugin..  [any help would be appreciated.](http://git.mrgray.com)..

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can animate fill color of the elements or groups of loaded SVGs. In the example "blue.svg" is a single rectangle.

Gotchas:

- You must use FF4+ or Chrome and I haven't tried Opera or Safari.
- Not all animations are supported on groups, and AFAIK not all
  animations in Keith Wood's jquery extension work in FF. Some
  animations can be done with css.
- Its "rect2816" not "svgblue" or "svgbox" because its the individual rectangle
  element you are animating, not the entire svg.
- Don't forget the CSS selector # is required when addressing the elements and the div they are in... "#rect2816" "#svgbox"
- Its "svgFill" not "fill" when using the jquery svg extension
- Use Inkscape to create SVGs

Load these libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.svg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.svganim.js" ></script>
```

Load the SVG:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  getsvg();  
})
function getsvg(){
  $("#svgbox").svg({  
    loadURL: 'blue.svg',  
    onLoad: main,  
    settings: {}  
  } );
}
```

Code to animate the rectangle, showing two ways to change fill:

```
function main(){

$('#svgblue').mouseover(function(){
    $('#rect2816').animate({ svgFill: red },2000);
});
   $('#svgblue').mouseout(function(){
$('#rect2816').css("fill", blue);
   });
}
```

**Note- on my box the repeated mouseover animation does not take the specified 2 seconds, so I may be doing something wrong with the mouseover.**

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, the svgFill animation animates the 'fill' attribute. A little test shows that the CSS 'fill' property always overrides the value of the SVG 'fill' attribute. I suppose that is intended behaviour.

> I can change the fill color of the group or individual paths like so:
>
> > svg.style('#group1 {fill: black}');
>
> Now when I try to animate the paths like this:
>
> > $('path').animate({svgFill: 'blue'}, 500);

Youre setting the initial value in the css, and trying to animate the attribute. As you found out, it doesnt work. At least not in my firefox.

One solution is, to not animate the attribute, but animate the css fill property. In order to animate colors you'll need jquery-color: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

To be able to animate the css fill property, you'll need to hook that in :

```
jQuery.Color.hook( "fill" );
```

*-pike