# Roll over JQuery -move

Tags: jquery

I have a simple button with an img. A double img: blue arrow at top, green arrow in bottom (hight 44px) . I cannot put the img in the background for different reasons. So I tried to put the img in the html and move it with jQuery. But it doesn't move. Anyone can help?
http://jsfiddle.net/uPd86/

HTML:

```
<div id="button">
  <div id="text">boto</div>
  <div id="arrow"><img src="http://www.mig-marketing.com/img/arrowDouble.png"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#button{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width:45px;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}    

#text{
    position:absolute; 
}

#arrow{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
}​
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){

    $("#button").hover(function() {
        $("#button #arrow").animate({top: "-22"}, 1200);
    });

})
```

​

Comment: Are you trying to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/uPd86/6/

Comment: Yes! perfect. Now I added some more complication with a svg. Do you know why the boto png works and the buto svg doesn't? it is just a copy. I have been hours and it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/ER9WT/

Comment: I have posted it as an answer, so if you feel it as an answer so you may accept it as an answer.

Comment: Moreover, (SVG) is a family of specifications of an XML-based file format for two-dimensional vector graphics, while (PNG) is a bitmapped image format that employs lossless data compression. To animate SVG file must read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369992/animating-externally-loaded-svg-with-keith-woods-jquery-svg-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/uPd86/6/

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

    $("#button").hover(function() {
        $("#button #arrow").animate({top: "-17px"}, 1200);
    }, function(){
        $("#button #arrow").animate({top: "0px"}, 1200);
    });

})
```

Comment: Both answers are correct and work fine. Thank you Ahsan and Keyur !

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution on codebins for rollover image using jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $("#button #arrow").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#button #arrow").animate({
            top: "-17"
        }, 500);
    });
    $("#button #arrow").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#button #arrow").animate({
            top: "0"
        }, 500);

    });
});
```

Try demo on: http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpb4

Comment: Both answers are correct and work fine. Thank you Ahsan and Keyur !